# How to use SuiteBarBrandingElement?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am looking at the default master page in SharePoint 2013 (v15.master) and there is a server control there `<SharePoint:SuiteBarBrandingElement runat="server"/>` which on the page renders as 'SharePoint'. I can't figure out where to change it to something else (without writing code behind).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information is thin, but there does not appear to be any UI-based way to get at this setting. But a setting it is (actually, a property on `SPWebApplication`).

Refer to this (unhelpful) documentation: [SPWebApplication.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.suitebarbrandingelementhtml%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Like you point out, you could write a solution to modify this property, but we can also use some PowerShell to get at it.

Executing this in the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell:

```
$app = Get-SPWebApplication http://my.sp2013.site/
$app.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml
```

Yields this output:

```
<div class="ms-core-brandingText">SharePoint</div>
```

This means that we can just assign a new value here:

```
$app.SuiteBarBrandingElementHtml = '<div class="ms-core-brandingText">Hello World!</div>'
$app.Update()
```

That aside, it would be pretty handy to build a solution that exposed the property via the Admin UI to update it. I don't know why Microsoft didn't provide this out of the box; it seems like that was the intention (at some point).

Comment: It really feels like there should be a UI setting for this, otherwise it doesn't make sense - how do you customize it without PowerShell?

Comment: @Andrey - Agreed, there *should* be a UI setting. It's entirely possible that Microsoft intended to provide one, but didn't have time to complete it. I don't know. For now, this is the only way I can find to accomplish the job without developing a UI solution of my own.